# Remove certain fields from a YAML map object using yq

Tags: yaml, yq

I have some tricky thing that I need to do for a yaml file, this is how it looks before

**Before**

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
  - apiVersion: core.k8s.com/v1alpha1
    kind: Test
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: '2022-02-097T19:511:11Z'
      finalizers:
        - cuv.ssf.com
      generation: 1
      name: bar
      namespace: foo
      resourceVersion: '12236'
      uid: 0117657e8
    spec:
      certificateIssuer:
        acme:
          email: myemail
      provider:
        credentials: dst
        type: foo
      domain: vst
      type: bar
    status:
      conditions:
        - lastTransitionTime: '2022-02-09T19:50:12Z'
          message: test
          observedGeneration: 1
          reason: Ready
          status: 'True'
          type: Ready
      lastOperation:
        description: test
        state: Succeeded
        type: Reconcile
```

https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/y22fe4943

I need to remove all the fields under section `metadata` and the tricky part is to keep only the `name` and `namespace`
in addition to removing the `status` section at all, it should look like following

**After**

```
  apiVersion: v1
    items:
      - apiVersion: core.k8s.com/v1alpha1
        kind: Test
        metadata:
          name: bar
          namespace: foo
        spec:
          certificateIssuer:
            acme:
              email: myemail
          provider:
            credentials: dst
            type: foo
          domain: vst
          type: bar
```

**After link**
https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/y220531ef

Using yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.19.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (aka Go yq), you could do something like below. Using [del](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/delete#delete-nested-entry-in-map) for deleting an entry and [with_entries](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/select#use-select-and-with_entries-to-filter-map-keys) for selecting known fields

```
yq '.items[] |= (del(.status) | .metadata |= with_entries(select(.key == "name" or .key == "namespace")))' yaml
```

Starting [v4.18.1](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.18.1), the `eval` flag is the default action, so the `e` flag can be avoided

Answer (score 1):

This should work using `yq` in the implementaion of https://github.com/kislyuk/yq (not https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), and the `-y` (or `-Y`) flag:

```sh
yq -y '.items[] |= (del(.status) | .metadata |= {name, namespace})'
```

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
  - apiVersion: core.k8s.com/v1alpha1
    kind: Test
    metadata:
      name: bar
      namespace: foo
    spec:
      certificateIssuer:
        acme:
          email: myemail
      provider:
        credentials: dst
        type: foo
      domain: vst
      type: bar
```

Comment: thanks, im getting an error `Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'y' in -y` any idea?

Comment: we are using the latest version

Comment: My yq has version 2.13.0. The manual says `--yaml-output, --yml-output, -y : Transcode jq JSON output back into YAML and emit it`. Maybe try one of the long forms.

Comment: Alternatively, use `--yaml-roundtrip, --yml-roundtrip, -Y : Transcode jq JSON output back into YAML and emit it. Preserve YAML tags and styles by representing them as extra items in their enclosing mappings and sequences while in JSON. This option is incompatible with jq filters that do not expect these extra items.`

Comment: I tried with ` yq --yaml-roundtrip   '.items[] |= (del(.status) | .metadata |= {name, namespace})' ~/projects/test/a.yaml`
` and get error `Error: unknown flag: --yaml-roundtrip
Usage:
  yq eval [expression] [yaml_file1]... [flags]
`

Comment: Then, I guess, something's wrong with your `yq` installation. Even the project's own [homepage](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) uses `-y` and `-Y` in their simple examples.

Comment: @pmf OP is using the Go yq

Comment: when I use the version I got `yq --version
yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version 4.19.1
`

Comment: @Inian Oh, okay. Does it work without parameters, then?

Comment: @pmf - any idea how to make it work with the go version?

Comment: Does it work without any parameters?

Comment: @pmf It tries so hard to be jq like, but not quite so yet. It used to have its own DSL, but starting to implement features like jq

Comment: @Alberto See my answer

Comment: The following should work:

`yq '.items[] |= (del(.status) | .metadata |=  {"name": .name,"namespace":.namespace})'`